# Can't resolve all parameters for DataService Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a generic service. I found this article: https://medium.com/@krishna.acondy/a-generic-http-service-approach-for-angular-applications-a7bd8ff6a068 which I have used to create my **DataService** which looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { Resource } from '../models/resource';
import { Serializer } from '../interfaces/serializer';

const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;

@Injectable()
export class DataService<T extends Resource> {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private endpoint: string,
    private serializer: Serializer) {}

  public create(item: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient
      .post<T>(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}`, this.serializer.toJson(item))
      .map(data => this.serializer.fromJson(data) as T);
  }

  public update(item: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient
      .put<T>(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}/${item.id}`,
        this.serializer.toJson(item))
      .map(data => this.serializer.fromJson(data) as T);
  }

  read(id: number): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`)
      .map((data: any) => this.serializer.fromJson(data) as T);
  }

  list(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}`)
      .map((data: any) => this.convertData(data.items));
  }

  delete(id: number) {
    return this.httpClient
      .delete(`${API_URL}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`);
  }

  private convertData(data: any): T[] {
    return data.map(item => this.serializer.fromJson(item));
  }
}
```

My **Serializer** looks like this:

```
import { Resource } from "../models/resource";

export interface Serializer {
    fromJson(json: any): Resource;
    toJson(resource: Resource): any;
}
```

And my **Resource** looks like this:

```
export class Resource {
    id: number
}
```

If I try to run my project, I get an error stating:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DataService: ([object Object], [object Object], ?).

It looks like it is having issues with the **Serializer**, but I can't see why.
I have commented out the **spec** file, so it isn't being used there and currently the **DataService** has not been extended, so I am not sure why it is moaning.
Does anyone know why?

---

The suggestion was to create a new serivce that extends the **DataService** (I had already tried that, but before I posted this question I deleted it to see if it was causing the issue.
Now I have re-created it and I am still getting the same error.

Here is my new class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { CategorySerializer } from '../models/category-serializer';
import { Category } from '../models/category';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService extends DataService<Category> {

  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    super(
      httpClient,
      'categories',
      new CategorySerializer()
    );
  }

}
```

and **Category** looks like this:

```
import { Resource } from "./resource";

export class Category extends Resource {
    name: string
}
```

and the most import **CategorySerializer** looks like this:

```
import { Serializer } from "../interfaces/serializer";
import { Category } from "./category";

export class CategorySerializer implements Serializer {
    fromJson(json: any): Category {
      const model = new Category();
      model.id = json.id;
      model.name = json.name;  
      return model;
    }

    toJson(model: Category): any {
      return {
        id: model.id,
        name: model.name
      };
    }
}
```

yet I still have the same error :(

Comment: `private serializer: Serializer` how does DI would know what kind of serialized to use?? Thats what `?` means

Comment: did u add this into provider list

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/Inject

Comment: @Antoniossss serializer is an interface, so as long as I have a class that implements the interface, should it not just work?

Comment: Exacly, it is just interface - did you specify what should be used as this interface implementation?(eg by `provides` module config) Angular is not a Spring... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Angular is having trouble resolving the Serializer is because there is no implementation of a Serializer object.

The serializer has been defined as an interface which can be thought of as an abstract class (it cannot be called directly but instead acts as a 'template' for classes to conform to). In order to use the serializer within a class you need to instantiate it to make it a real object that can be interacted with. To do this you need to create a class that extends your serializer interface and then call to that.

In the example you posted, this has been made to work generically which removes some clarity from what is happening but essentially you need a concrete class to implement (they use PizzaSerializer)

[image]

When they instantiate the service itself they pass through a newly instantiated version of a Serializer (with the **new** key word) which will be used by the constructor as a type of Serializer.

Make sure you have a serializer that extends your Serializer class and that is passed to the Service constructor.

Comment: what you are saying is that if I create an actual class that extends the DataService, the error will go away if I have a Serializer that implements the Serializer interface?

Comment: Correct. If your CategorySerializer has been added to the module 'provider' list the   CategoryService should handle the injection of that new class with all its required dependencies. Has it been added to the module list?

Comment: No, I didnt realise it had to be added there :)